# Prestashop 1.5.6 How to add a link to external site instead of add to cart button

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

I am using Prestashop 1.5.6. I need to give link to the external site instead of the add to cart button. How it is possible? Does the Prestashop have any option to give an external link to the product or any module for that?

Comment: line 20 of modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.tpl

Comment: Alternatively if it's changed in this version, always try checking `product-list.tpl`

Comment: Ohgodwhy Thanks for your reply,Can you mentioned the path of the product-list.tpl file

Comment: It's not possible by default. You'd have to modify each instance of the "add to cart".